# Every request generates new session

Tags: javascript

i am new to MERN stack and i don't know why it generates a new session every request. Whenever i request new session/reload the app from the client side which is the react app it always prompt new session id in the backend console.

```js
import Express, {
  json
} from 'express'
import * as http from 'http'
import cors from 'cors'
import session from 'express-session'
import {
  config
} from 'dotenv'
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo'
import {
  createHmac,
  createHash,
  scryptSync,
  randomBytes,
  timingSafeEqual
} from 'crypto'
import connection, {
  connectToDb
} from './Services/Connection.js'
connectToDb();
const app = Express()
const port = 5000
const server = http.createServer(app);
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(json())
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'],
}))

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  proxy: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    expires: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    sameSite: 'none',
    httpOnly: true
  },
  store: MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: process.env.DB_URI,
    ttl: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    autoRemove: "native",

  }),
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
}))
app.post('/api/login', async (req,res)=>{
  const user = req.body;
  if(user.type=="guest"){
    const guest = await connection.db.collection("user").insertOne({
        ...user,
    })
    currentSession ={
      ...req.session,
      user:user
    }
    console.log(guest)
    return;
  }
  const found = await connection.db.collection("user").findOne({
    email:user.email
  })
  const [salt,password] = found.password.split(":");
  const buffPass = Buffer.from(password,"hex",64);
  const hashPass = scryptSync(user.password,salt,64);
  if(found._id!=undefined && timingSafeEqual(buffPass,hashPass)){
    req.session.user = found;
    req.session.save((err)=>{
        if(err){
          return res.send(500);
        }
        res.send(req.session)    
    })  
  }else{
    res.send("NO USER FOUND")
  }
})
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})



fetch('/api/login',{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials:'same-origin',
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
    }).then((e)=>{
      console.log("SUCCESS");
      navigate("/type=client")
    }).catch((r)=>{
      console.log("FAILD")
    })
```

Here is my fetch from client side as of now it still generates new session but if i try to fetch directly from the backend it is working fine.
I don't know what ive done wrong maybe there is something with my package.json on the client side. i just the "proxy":"http://localhost:5000" to it. Maybe i need something to make it work?

Comment: are you sure your client sents the required cookie? Session id is stored in a cookie, typicially. If this cookie is not sent, the server has no id to lookup an existing session.

Comment: Where are you logging the session id to the backend console? Please include that code, as well as the HTTP requests that your frontend is making

Comment: the request is just like this: fetch(/session,{credentials:same-origin})

Comment: i also did use the include but still it generates new session id

Comment: while the session api is just an api that return the req.session. Am i doing something wrong? it is the right way of fetching the current session. Thank you guys in advance!!!

Comment: How did you implement the `/session` route on the server? So far you've only shown the login code